Windows MAUI not showing images after upgrade
After a few days without working on a MAUI app, I returned to it today only to have it blow up on my face.
Loudly.
After a few searches online (described here), I was able to make it work again.
Sort of.
Now, the images are not showing.
Has anyone encountered something similar?
All images are defined as MauiImage.
And the image control is pretty basic:
<Image 
    Source="animated.gif"
    HeightRequest="100"
    WidthRequest="100"
    IsAnimationPlaying="True"
    VerticalOptions="End"/>


Do you mean that only the GIF images are not displayed, or is it that the images in other formats are not displayed either?

None of the images.

You can try to delete the bin folder and the obj folder and rebuild it. If it doesn’t work, try to restart the VS.
